# How to find the accuracy of my confusion matrix?

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

In my data, I've been able to create a confusion matrix:

```
cm<- table(predict(model,newdata=as.matrix(dat2[,-(1:2)])),dat2$r)
cm

##        0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
##   0  126    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
##   1    3  483    7    1   12   11    8    7
##   2    1   14 1413    1   60   47   53   46
##   3    0    0    0   90    0    0    0    0
##   4   27   92  144    5 6566  308  500  236
##   5    4   24   63    3  129 1899  201   35
##   6    2   14   40    0   82  100 1994   40
##   7    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  375
```

How do I find the accuracy of this confusion matrix? Or do 1 - error rate so how do I find the error rate? Thanks guys.

Comment: Try `caret::confusionMatrix()` function. It will provide many statistics including accuracy.

Comment: I tried but Im getting all sorts of error with confusionMatrix function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the accuracy

```py
sum(diag(cm))/sum(cm)
```

where `diag` is all of the values across the diagonal of your matrix.

Comment: The formula for accuracy is the number of correct predictions divided by the total number of predictions.  The formula above adds the counts along the diagonal of the confusion matrix (which are all of the correct predictions) and divides it by the number of predictions (the sum of all counts in the confusion matrix).